# How to get an image URI from the cursor?

Tags: java, android, android-cursor

I am new to Android development and I am trying to make app that displays all the images in the phone.

I am trying to implement this using CursorAdapter class.

My code is,

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.photo_list);

        Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
        );

        MyCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
        gridView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

MyCursorAdapter.java

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.photo_image);
        String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

The app works properly. But the thing that is annoying me is this one.

```
String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
```

The constant DATA is deprecated and its comment is saying

```
         * Absolute filesystem path to the media item on disk.
         * <p>
         * Note that apps may not have filesystem permissions to directly access
         * this path. Instead of trying to open this path directly, apps should
         * use {@link ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String)} to gain
         * access.
         *
         * @deprecated Apps may not have filesystem permissions to directly
         *             access this path. Instead of trying to open this path
         *             directly, apps should use
         *             {@link ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String)}
         *             to gain access.
```

openFileDescriptor() method requires Uri and String. But, as you can see in my code, I am using DATA contant to get Uri so I can't pass the Uri to openFileDescriptor() method and don't know what String arguments to be passed to openFileDescriptor().

In this situation, what should I do to write without using DATA constant?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: `But, as you can see in my code, I am using DATA contant to get Uri ` No. No uri but a string. A path. To get the real uri get the ID column and use uriWithAppendedPath or uriWithAppendedId or however it is called.

Comment: @blackapps, Thank you for the hint! I solved the issue. XD

Answer (score 1):

With the help of blackapps, I removed the DATA constant and got the same result.

Differences are as below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
    );
```

to

```
    Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
            null,
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
    );
```

Above change is optional but adding a projection argument to the getContentResolver().query will make query efficient.

**MyCursorAdapter.java**

```
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.photo_image);
    String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

to

```
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.photo_image);
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
    Glide.with(context).load(ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)).into(imageView);
```

I'd tried to get index from _ID constant and got the uri using **ContentUris.withAppendedId()** method.

If there's anything wrong, please let me know!

Once again, thank you blackapps.